# jQuery - Draggable / stay in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here is a short explanation of my problem:
Before i drag my element, it stays in its position after I resize the window. But when i start dragging it around, then try to resize the window again, it won't stay in its container.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bqr0qpj/) to demonstrate my problem.
Here is my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".MENU").draggable({
    containment: ".MENU-CONTAINER",
    snap: ".MENU-CONTAINER",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: "16",
    scroll: false
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1.00);
}

.MAIN {
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.MENU-CONTAINER {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 0.3);
}

.MENU {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 64px;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="MAIN">
  <div class="MENU-CONTAINER">
    <div class="MENU"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get this element to follow its container after changing the size of the viewport (i.e. preserve containment after a window resize)?

Answer (score 1):

Add a reload after each window resize

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(".MENU").draggable({
  containment: ".MENU-CONTAINER",
  snap: ".MENU-CONTAINER",
  snapMode: "inner",
  snapTolerance: "16",
  scroll: false
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1.00);}

.MAIN {
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.MENU-CONTAINER {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.MENU {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 64px;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="MAIN">
  <div class="MENU-CONTAINER">
    <div class="MENU"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there another way to do this instead of refreshing the page?

Comment: This is clearly not a satisfactory solution because it reloads the page moving the draggable to the original position but I couldn't find a good way to force a redraw